# I can't change the boot disk when I try to create a Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to create a new instance for deep learning on Google Cloud Platform, by following various tutorials including   **http://cs231n.github.io/gce-tutorial/**, I can't select a zone or boot disk (I'd like to use Ubuntu 16.04. There is no response when I click these features. How can I set them?[image]

Comment: Hello, would it be possible for you to include a screen shot with English text? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce this issue with various levels of authorisation in my own project and I've not been able to reproduce this issue. As you have access to the Create Instance page, It looks to like this might be a browser specific issue, rather than and issue with authorisation, or any settings within your project.

Would it be possible for you to try and perform this task from a different browser and see if the result is the same? For example, can you try this in Chrome browser and in an Incognito window? 
If you are able to perform the action from a different browser, you probably have an issue with cookies, or a third-party browser add on affecting the functionality with GCP. You could try enabling the cookies for the browser to see if that makes a difference, or disabling/removing third party add ons to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: thank you for you suggestions and I do use chrome on a win10 pc to produce these issues.

Comment: Could you please post a screen shot for a "correct" way of settings for a project ? (I just use the default way)

Comment: thank for your advice and I have bult them successfully by firefox in my local VM

Comment: Excellent, so just to clarify, has your issue been resolved by following this advice? Is so please can you accept my answer by clicking the 'tick' to the left of the answer.